# Still getting a error message of subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I run I get error of subscript out of range, data workbook is opened as well.

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim IntialName As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant


    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    Workbooks("data").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
    Workbooks("data").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AVI").Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

    IntialName = "AVI" & Date
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("AVI " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy"), fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: What line produces the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the file extension

```
Workbooks("data.xlsx").Activate
```

Comment: I put your code in excel and ran it, it does work, so perhaps you can specify what exactly is happening - it must be one of those annoying little things. Make sure the name of the workbook matches and has the correct extension.